# What's the easiest way to invoke a Spring.NET service exposed over remoting using Python

Tags: python, rest, spring.net

I have a .NET 3.5 service that is currently exposed using Spring.NET 1.2 over .NET Remoting. I would like to invoke service methods from Python, so am looking for the quickest and easiest way to achieve this.

Options I am exploring are:

- Expose the service via REST (is this possible with Spring.NET 1.2, or can it be done separately without affecting the existing Remoting interface?)
- Invoke the .NET Remoting calls from Python (the marshalling issues make me think this approach is a non-starter)
- Something else?

Any suggestions?

**Update**: The service interface is trivial -- it does not use any advanced features such as callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the services you're exposing, exporting a plain old CLR object as an asmx web service [*can* be trivial in 1.2](http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.2.0/reference/html/webservices.html), with only a configuration change.

.NET Remoting has functionality that can't be exposed by asmx and REST services (e.g. callback objects, lifetime specification etc) and if your application is relying on that, it might be a bit more difficult or even impossible.

You need to post more information on your service interface to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: I expect there to be a decent asmx web service library, but have not tried it.

Comment: An asm library for Python that is.

Comment: The service interface is trivial -- it does not use any advanced features such as callbacks.

Comment: Then you can probably switch the configuration of a remoting proxy to an asmx web service proxy. Let us know how that went.

Comment: I gave up trying to understand the over-complicated and under-documented Spring.NET malarkey and just set up a straight WCF wrapper to expose the service methods I'm interested in. Sorry, my brain's not big enough.

Comment: Sounds like a fine solution to me :)